# $L^{1}$ bounded solution of elliptic equation implies $L^{\infty}$ boundedness

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

$Lu=\Delta u+hu$ is an elliptic operator with $h$ smooth  on $\overline{\Omega}$. $u_{\alpha}$ is a family of solution of $Lu=0$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$.And we know $|\int_{\Omega}u_{\alpha}|\leq C.$Can we derive that $u_{\alpha}$ is uniformly bounded on $\Omega$?

This is a step in a paper I'm reading recently.The author says this is true but I cannot figure it out.Any help will be thanked.

Comment: Did you mean $\int_{\Omega}{|u_{\alpha}|} \leq C$? Did you mean “uniformly bounded” on compacts of $\Omega$ or on all of $\Omega$? Is $h$ smooth just on $\Omega$ or on $\overline{\Omega}$?

Comment: @Aphelli I've edited it.But I'm sorry that the author just says 'uniformly bounded' so I'm not quite sure about his idea.So any relevant estimate of reference will be thanked.

Comment: @Tree23  So ur problem is when the solutions are not continuous on $\Omega$ but why would they not be continuous ? Are u looking for solution is distribution sense ? Assuming continuous solutions, So i think you need to prove that continuous function on a bounded domain which is integrable must converge to a finite limit in boundary ?

Comment: @Balajisb Why uniformly bounded when solution is continuous?I need a bounded irrelevant to $\alpha$.

Comment: @Tree23 I thought unformly bounded on domain $\Omega$ and not on $\alpha$. If you need it on $\alpha$, may be try to argue that $u_{\alpha}$ is continuous on $\Omega \times \{\text{domain of } \alpha\}$.

Comment: I think Theorem 3.1 in https://math.mit.edu/~rbm/18-155-F17/Chapter4.pdf should solve your problem, because if $M$ is small enough, the $\|\cdot\|_M$ Sobolev norm is controlled by the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: Though I find the $\left|\int_{\Omega}{u_{\alpha}}\right| \leq C$ weird. What’s preventing us to pick $h$ such that some solution $u$ has integral zero, and then consider the family of the $\lambda u$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Tree23 Look for inequalities in norm conjugate to $L^p$  for solution in $L^p$ treating the equation in distribution sense. This will give inequality in $L^{\infty}$ for $p=1$.